# VBA sub to search Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to add a subroutine to a VBA macro which does a search for a value ("tag") in an Excel sheet "LB Rack", in range B2:B200.
    If the tag is found, I want it to run another sub, "InsertSVblock".
    If tag is not found, I want it to output a Msgbox message, and run sub            "CheckforLBmatch(tag)", which searches another sheet.

My method is to do a VLOOKUP on the range, and check for error 1004.

It's working up to a point - if it doesn't find a match, it outputs the error message, and runs "CheckforLBmatch(tag)". But how can I get it to run "InsertSVblock", if a match is found?
Or is there a better way to do this?

```
Public Sub CheckforLBmatch(tag)

Dim xlApp As excel.Application
Dim xlbook As excel.Workbook
Dim xlSht As excel.Worksheet
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\LB_RACKTMC.xlsx")
Set xlSht = xlbook.Sheets("LB RACK")
Set LBrng = xlSht.Range("B2:B200")

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

       Debug.Print xlApp.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tag, LBrng, 3, False)

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "No SV component in LB Rack for " & tag
    Err.Clear
    CheckforET200match (tag)
    End If
  Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm) is a good resource on using find.  It goes through a case on how to check if anything is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Range.Find()` method. Based on your code I'm assuming you're calling this sub from a different Office application and you have set a reference to the Excel Objects library:

```
Sub CheckForLBMatch(tag As Variant)

Dim xlApp           As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook          As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet         As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlSearchRange   As Excel.Range
Dim xlFoundRange    As Excel.Range

    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\07509\LB_RACKTMC.xlsx")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets("LB RACK")
    Set xlSearchRange = xlSheet.Range("B2:B200")
    Set xlFoundRange = xlSearchRange.Find(tag)

    If xlFoundRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The value (" & CStr(tag) & ") could not be found!", vbOkOnly + vbInformation
        CheckForET200Match tag
    Else
        InsertSVblock
    End If

xlBook.Close False '// Optional [SaveChanges] argument

Set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run the "CheckForLBMatch" sub, it acts as if it did find the value. If I remove the "Not", it outputs the MsgBox message (which is what should happen) ...??

Comment: @tmccar sorry, got mixed up there! Remove the `Not` as you suggested and its right, I'll edit the answer too

Answer (score 0):

When I started working with VBA, I found myself trying to accomplish all Excel functionality with Macros; however, that is sometimes less efficient than simply using Excel.

I would hardcode the VLOOKUP into the worksheet. That way you can separate your code into cases based on the value of the cell and test it much more easily. If `IsNumeric(Cell.Value)`, run your subroutine, else handle the issue.